# Quadratic expression into postfix notation

Tags: quadratics

I know generally how to convert an infix expression into a postfix expression; but I came lately across this quadratic expression: $\left(4y^2 + 2x - 1\right)$ that I had to convert into postfix and it raised a couple of questions for me, namely:

If I have the following expression: $4y^2$ would I treat $4y$ as just one operand or $2$ separate operands?
I believe that the postfix equivalent of $4y^2$ would be:  `4y2^*`

Thank you in advance for clearing this ambiguity for me!

Comment: Why not y2^4*2x*+1-?

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall, Because, if I intend to evaluate this expression programatically, using a stack, then I will have to start with the first operand and keep processing the string so that at the end it will look like:  4y2^*2x*+1-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implicit parenthesization of $4y^2$ is $4(y^2)$, so your `4y2^*` is correct.

Comment: @nathan: Although it yields the same value, that doesn’t correspond to the original expression. (And there is no ambiguity.)

Comment: Alright, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this of interest:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm.

The article contains a detailed, generalized description of an algorithm that converts tokenized infix expressions into reverse-Polish.